# ipython notebook: custom cells and execute hook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I would like to override what happens when run is pressed for certain cells in ipython notebook.

For example, I would like to be able to write an SQL query directly in a cell and define a function that processes it.

It seems it should be possible to do this as with [ipython-notebook extensions](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/IPython-notebook-extensions). Does anyone know of a similar extension? An easy way to do this directly from ipython?

Ideally this would involve defining a custom cell type, but I would be happy to use special tags to separate the usual python code from, say, a custom SQL query cell.

Comment: The [IPython Extension index](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/wiki/Extensions-Index) suggest [this SQL](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipython-sql) extension. Maybe this can help you.

Comment: Thanks. ipython magic commands (https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/config/custommagics.html) indeed is a way to solve this. The only small issue is that I'm not able to assign a result of a cell magic to a variable, using "_" makes it a bit ugly.

Answer (score 5):

I've once had the similar desire and I ended up with the following solution:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd
from IPython.core.magic import register_cell_magic
from IPython import get_ipython
con = create_engine(DB_URL)

@register_cell_magic
def sql(line, cell):
    cell = cell.format(**globals())
    if line.strip() != '-':
        res = pd.read_sql(cell, con)
        if line.strip() != '': get_ipython().user_ns[line.strip()] = res
        return res
    else:
        con.execute(cell)
del sql
```

You can now write in other cells:

```
%sql outputvar
select * from whatever where ...
```

For example:

[image: Screenshot]